# In LINQ to SQL, how can you convert a string to an int?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, type-conversion

I have a table in the database that contains a `varchar` field that `integer` data is stored in. How can I convert the `string` to an `int` in a LINQ function so that I can query on that field? Neither `Convert.toInt32()` nor `int.parse()` work inside a LINQ Entities function (they work when you're querying a list that's already in memory, but not when the function chain is going to be converted to a SQL query and sent to be executed by the database).

Comment: LINQ to SQL? As in, the decade old precursor to Entity Framework? Just want to make sure as LINQ to SQL is dead and you probably shouldn't use it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make an entity that matches the schema of the sql table ***Exactly***.

Make another model that matches your business needs and make a method to map your entity to your business model.

Comment: So, in other words, there is no way to do it? Even though SQL is perfectly capable of converting a string to an int, Linq to SQL has no features that can translate into a SQL CAST() or CONVERT() function?

Comment: Not that I know about. If there was some way it may be unnecessarily complex. This method, as far as I know, has been the standard anywhere I've worked. How do you handle if the parse fails? If it's null?

Comment: I agree that this sounds more like a business concern. Why isn't the field an integer in the database to begin with if that's the desired type?

Answer (score 0):

There's no supported conversion from string to integer in Linq to SQL. However, there is a utility class that has methods that can be converted into SQL expression.
`System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions` has methods that are supported in Linq to Sql. So in your case, You can convert your local integer to string using `SqlFunctions.StringConvert()` and compare them.

```
E.g. yourTable.Where(r => r.Field == SqlFunction.StringConvert(<your integer>));
```

Comment: This would be good for querying. I believe he also wants his model to contain the result as an integer so it would need to convert the query result.

Comment: Just call ToList() on the linq query that will load the collection in memory and will support the .Net convert methods.